# Rails has_many chain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

So I have a table structure below:

**Plane**

- plane_id
- plane_info

**Seating**

- seating_id
- seating_info

**PlaneSeating**

- plane_seating_id
- plane_id
- seating_id

**PlaneSeatingNote**

- plane_seating_note_id
- plane_seating_id
- note_id

**Note**

- note_id
- note_info

This gives me a third-normal DB, but I need to set the model relations up.

I currently have:

```
class Plane < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :plane_seatings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :seatings, through: :plane_seatings

end

class Seatings < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :plane_seatings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :planes, through: :plane_seatings

end

class PlaneSeating < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :plane
  belongs_to :seating
  has_many :plane_seating_notes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :notes, through: :plane_seating_notes

end

class PlaneSeatingNote < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :plane_seating
  has_one :note

end

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Now, this will give me the ability to say `Plane.all.first.plan_seatings.first.notes` and get the notes I believe. However, I'd like to be able to say `Plane.all.first.seatings.notes` and get the notes associated with that plane given that seating.

My thought is there should be a way to say, in Plane:

```
has_many :seatings, through: plane_seating, has_many :notes, through: plane_seating
```

or some other chaining magic to get a seating with some notes that only apply to that plane and seating combo. a :with, if you will. But I can't think of any syntax that would give me that. Anyone know?

Comment: Quick note, there's no need to do `all.first`, just do `.first` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a helper method in the Plane model to get what I wanted. This method may be inefficient if you are dealing with large datasets, but for my datasets, it works fine. It packages up each seating subset for each plane with the notes associated with it into a hash.

```
  #Get an easy to read hash of the seatings with their notes
  def seatings_with_notes
    @seatings_with_notes = []
    self.plane_seatings.each do |item|
      seating = Seating.where(id: item.product_application_id).first
      notes = item.notes
      combo = {seating:seating, notes:notes}
      @seatings_with_notes.append(combo)
    end
    return @seatings_with_notes
  end
```

Comment: I think it's the right idea to accomplish this by adding an instance method to the model. However, you are right about inefficient performance. Your method will make a SQL read once for each iteration in order to get the associated data. If you wrote all the SQL by hand, you could accomplish this with 1-2 SQL reads. Even if it makes 10 reads it is better, just as long as it doesn't read once per iteration. I recommend reading about `N+1` in ActiveRecord as well as learning some more advanced `ActiveRecord::Query` methods, `pluck`, and  `find_by_sql`.

Answer (score 2):

The best is to pivot it the other way, it you want to grab the notes for a certain Plane:

```
Note.joins(plane_seating_note: [:plane_seating]).where(plane_seating_note: {plane_seating: {plane_id: 1})
```

You could make that a scope if you're using it in multiple places and if you want it on the Plane model:

```
class Plane < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :plane_seatings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :seatings, through: :plane_seatings

  def notes
    @notes ||= Note.for_plane_id id
  end

end

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :plane_seating_notes

  scope :for_plane_id ->(plane_id) { joins(plane_seating_notes: [:plane_seating]).where(plane_seating_notes: {plane_seating: {plane_id: plane_id}) }

end
```

For a specific seat on a specific plane, you'd typically see something like this in a controller:

```
@seat  = PlaneSeat.find params[:id]
@plane = @seat.plane
@notes = Note.joins(:plane_seating_notes).where(plane_seating_notes: {plane_seating_id: @seat.id})
```

But since you have a HMT you could just do

```
@seat  = PlaneSeat.find params[:id]
@plane = @seat.plane
@notes = @seat.notes
```

A couple "Rails-way" notes:

1. Unless you are using Note elsewhere, you should just skip the plane_seat_notes.
2. Consider using has_and_belongs_to_many if you aren't appending any extra meta-data in the intermediate table; this makes relationships easier and gives you shallower query helpers
3. Consider using polymorphic relationships rather than unnecessary join tables

Comment: I concur regarding removing the `plane_seat_notes` table, I was thinking the same.

Comment: The notes are static, which is why I have the plane_seat_notes. Say I have note 1, "expensive" and 2, "cheap", those notes can be applied variably. So plane_seating 1 has notes 1 and 2, but plan_seating 2 has note 1 and plane_seating 3 has no notes.

Comment: Also, I notice this is how to link everything up in the controller. Is there no way to do this through the models? Your #2 and #3 interest me, but how would I go about doing those?

Comment: I'm not convinced this gets at what I'm trying to do. It seems to flatten the relationship of notes to a specific plane. I want the notes on a specific plane for a seating that is also specific to that plane. Example. Plane.first.seatings.first.notes would give notes for that seating on that plane. However, I could not call Seatings.first.notes or Plane.first.notes because the notes are tied to both ids, not just one. Does your code account for this?

Comment: @steventnorris in that case you'll have `PlaneSeating.where(plane_id: Plane.first, seating_id: Seating.first).notes` or `Plane.first.plane_seatings.where(seating_id: Seating.first).notes`